# C# Visual studio for mac: intellisense is autocompleting wrong . Option to disable?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, polymorphism

Given two classes that inherit from each other (Animal -> Cow) , with the childclass overriding a method (MakeSound). When I iterate over a list of Animals and write the following :
`if(animal is Cow){`

If I then want add in the if - statement:
`animal.MakeSound();`

The autocompletion changes it to :

`((Cow)animal). MakeSound`

This is not wrong in itself, but largely redundant since I override MakeSound and so don't need to cast to a Cow.

Is there any way to disable this redundant autocompletion behaviour in  VS for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

According to a quick google search, it appears there might not be a current way to turn off this particular feature, at least not easily when using VS for Mac (which in all other cases other than this is quite useful so I recommend reconsidering that particular course of action).

However I'd like to challenge your request. I think the confusion here is that you state:

```
if (animal is Cow){
    animal.MakeSound();
}
```

You told the compiler that the type of `animal` is important by checking that it is a `Cow`, but then you say you DON'T care about the type of `animal` because the method is virtual. So I suggest reconsidering how you've organized your code here. Either the type of `animal` matters, or it doesn't. If the body of your if check contains `Cow` specific logic, consider moving your call to `MakeSound()` to somewhere else where type doesn't matter.